# How to change the case of a table name in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I want to change a table name  in SQLite so that it is all lowercase. This command fails:

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table RENAME TO my_table;

Error: there is already another table or index with this name: my_table
```

I know SQLite commands are case-insensitive, but I need this for reasons external to SQLite. I should also say that I want to automate the process.

One feasible solution is to do it in two steps:

1. rename the table using a temporary name, and
2. rename the table from the temporary name to the lowercase name:

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table RENAME TO My_Table_tmp;
ALTER TABLE My_Table_tmp RENAME TO my_table;
```

However a failsafe scheme to chose a temporary name is not obvious to me as a table with the temporary name `My_Table_tmp` (for example) could already exist, maybe from some failed attempt prior. I realize these could be rare cases, but I am still interested in knowing if anyone has a single-step solution.

Comment: So is it `my_table` or `current_wf`?

Comment: `my_table`: question corrected.

Comment: Are you saying you tried the 2-step process and it didn't work?

Comment: No 2-step works. My question is: there a single step way?

Comment: Following a downvote I clarified the question.

Comment: Is there some reason you wouldn't just do the two renames in a transaction, and rollback on any failures?

Comment: I guess it would only fail on the first transaction (rename to temp), and therefore there would not even be a need to rollback. What I will do is generate a random string long enough that there's virtually no chance of name collision. I guess I just wanted to know if there was a feature I did not know about in SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html
The error you get indeed because SQLite is case insensitive so:
first rename to e.g. xyz_table_42 then to my_table
As far as I know for said reason a 1-step way is not possible

Comment: This answer is a reformulation of information already contained in the question.